# How to make a section with one side without container restrictions

Tags: html, css

I have a container that I use for each section. I need to make one section so that on the right it is completely pressed against the right side of the browser window, that is, there are no restrictions of the container on the right, and on the left so that it is limited and is on the same level as the sections below with the container. On larger screens, the left side should be in place, flush with the other sections. And when slowing down, move like other sections. How can you create such a section?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1230px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red
}

.section-1 {
  height: 600px;
}

.section-1__content {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

.section-2__content {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="section-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-1__content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-2">
    <div class="section-2__content"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Grid can do that. Here's an example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.main-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50vw 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40vh;
}

.section-1 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}

.section-2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}

.section-1__content {
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.section-2__content {
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="section-1">
    <div class="section-1__content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-2">
    <div class="section-2__content"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
```